# Rails : Fastest way to copy large (jsonb) database from production to development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, database-backups

I have often the needs to copy my production database into my dev environment. For that I have a rake task that pull the database from my production server creating a .dump file then I recreate from scratch my development database.

Here is my rake task :

```
namespace :db do
    desc 'Pull production db to development'
    task :pull => [:dump, :restore]
  
    task :dump do
      dumpfile = "#{Rails.root}/tmp/latest.dump"
      puts 'PG_DUMP on production database...'
      production = Rails.application.config.database_configuration['production']
      system "ssh root@my_prod_server 'postgres:export prod-db' > #{dumpfile}"
      puts 'Done!'
    end
  
    task :restore do
      dev = Rails.application.config.database_configuration['development']
      dumpfile = "#{Rails.root}/tmp/latest.dump"
      puts 'PG_RESTORE on development database...'
      system "pg_restore --verbose --clean --no-acl --no-owner -h 127.0.0.1 -U #{dev['username']} -d #{dev['database']} #{dumpfile}"
      puts 'Done!'
    end
  end
```

It's working great.

The problem is, it's start to becoming bigger and bigger and for each row I have large amount of `jsonb` data. At this moment my latest.dump file is around 700MB and take ~5min to perform.

Is there any other solution than this to speed up this process. Would this be possible to just copy/paste the whole DB at once instead of recreating every row from scratch every time ?

Thanks !

Comment: To answer better I'd like to know what you're doing with this copy. Can you provide some situations?

Comment: Thanks @Schwern for your detailed answer. I copy my production database when I need to reproduce a bug or do some testing with real life data. Not for statistic or reports. So the follower database in read-only, as you and jjanes suggested, is quite interesting for me ! Not sure how to implement it though, any reference about that ? I will also consider converting my jsonb data to proper column in the future, but later.

Comment: See [Chapter 27. High Availability, Load Balancing, and Replication](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/high-availability.html). I pay [Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-follower-databases) to deal with this.

Comment: Yes thanks I think I will create a "replica" database on my server that I can connect to when needed for my test :)

Answer (score 4):

As you're discovering, copying your production database to development does not scale. In addition to the sheer size, there is are security issues and [PII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personal_data) concerns with developers being able to access, let alone have root access to and copy, the production database.

Regardless of what you're doing with the data, copying the production database should not be a regular part of the development process. If you're doing this regularly, question your process. It should be slow and difficult so developers avoid doing it.

Depending on what you're doing, better alternatives are...

## Use a follower database

Set up a database which continually follows production. Connect your development environment to that. There are still PII concerns with letting developers connect to a follower, but the database is read-only so the developers cannot accidentally damage the data.

This is useful for realistic performance testing, or to investigate a nasty bug which requires investigation of production data.

And, as [jjanes answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70615393/14660) it can be detached and promoted to being a read-write database.

A follower is also useful for production. Expensive read-only queries which don't require up-to-the-second accuracy such as reports, statistics, and summaries can be done on the follower.

## Use FactoryBot and Faker

If you just need realistic test data, use tools such as [FactoryBot](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot/) and [Faker](https://github.com/faker-ruby/faker) to easily create complex, interconnected data.

---

You can also reduce the size of your production database.

## Use a data warehouse

Often only a fraction of the data in the production database is needed for production. The rest is old data useful for auditing, statistics, and analysis.

You can reduce the size of your production database by moving historical data into a [data warehouse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_warehouse) such as [Google BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/). Then do your audits, statistics, and analysis on the data warehouse; it's much better set up for that.

## Turn jsonb into real columns

jsonb is appropriate for unstructured data where you're not sure what will be stored. It is not a substitute for a proper schema. Consider what you're putting into jsonb and consider whether it would be better served by a real column. This can reduce the size of your database.

Answer (score 2):

You could set up a hot standby so that it is following along just behind production.  Then when you need it, just promote it to read-write and it has become your new dev.  It should only take a fraction of second to promote (assuming it existed and was not too far behind to start with).  Then immediately start standing up the next hot standby so that it is ready to go when you want it.

Comment: Thanks that make sense ! Any reference on how to implement this process of "follower database" and how to connect to it on-demand ?